# What is the meaning of formal behavior?

Tags: formality, dictionaries

I've looked in the dictionaries and I looked in Dictionary.com for "Formal" and it says "excessively ceremonious" what would ceremonious mean? According to the dictionary it says "following ceremony" and it makes me wonder... why cannot English dictionaries be so simple?

Comment: Have you tried searching this online or asking the question on out sister site [ell.se]?

Comment: Yes, however I did not find what I was looking for.

Comment: It is a rather formal greeting for family and friends. I would only use it in a jocular sense. An acquaintance of mine used to greet me in such a way, but he was a pretty [*cold fish*](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/cold-fish). I never really liked him.

Comment: No they are not too formal to use for family and friends, nor is *good morning*.